# I can't see package and python library after upgrade pip

Tags: python, pip, upgrade

After i upgraded pip, When i use `pip list`  in cmd, it does not show libraries and packages of python that i install with previous version of pip, and it show only libraries that installed with last pip version

Now, what has happened for libraries and packages, and how can i see libraries and packages?

Comment: The only change you made is upgrading pip?

Comment: I found it. i installed python 3.6 before upgrading pip. This caused when i use 'pip list', it show only libraries that installed python 3.6.  Now i use 'pip3.8 list' to see all packages that installed python 3.8

Comment: On a somewhat related note, here is an article with some solid advice: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/